# C++ implementation of queue using array

Tags: c++

I have written this code after studying from Introduction to Algorithm. I think this code is very basic and simple. I want to modify it.

```
#include <iostream>
int tail;
int head;

void initialise_head_tail(){
tail=0;
head=0;
}

void enqueue(int a[],int x,int s){
a[tail]=x;
if( tail+1==s)
    tail=0;
else
    tail++;
}

int dequeue(int a[],int s){
int x=a[head];
if(head+1==s)
    head=0;
else
    head++;
return x;
}
int main()
{
    initialise_head_tail();
    int a[5];
    enqueue(a,15,5);
    enqueue(a,6,5);
    enqueue(a,9,5);
    enqueue(a,8,5);
    enqueue(a,4,5);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        std::cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<"\n"<<dequeue(a,5);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to learn if I can apply some better logic. I was thinking to use vector instead of array but there are already methods push_back() and pop_back(). Can we use vector?

Comment: If you'll replace `std::cout` with `printf` this is going to become pure C. I don't really see any advantage in using C++ with current design.

Comment: You can only have a single (sane) queue per program. To have other queues, you would have to get rid of the older ones. So you have to queue your queues.

Comment: Should I use vector?

Comment: Please explain your code a little bit...

Comment: @abhi11095, yes, but it is not biggest problem here. First thing to settle would be encapsulation. You could wrap this into a class, so it would be more reusable.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Distributing the internal state of your queue over some globals and two arguments is an *interesting* decision. At least that way you can get the worst of all worlds.
2. `enqueue` assumes the queue is not full, `dequeue` assumes it is not empty. That's also a questionable decision.
3. You know that streaming a char is more efficient than streaming a length-1-string?
4. `return 0;` is implicit for `main()` in C++ and C99+.
5. I wonder why you wrap a conditional statement into its own block exactly one time. Some advocate using a block everywhere, others only where needed, but both camps are united in wanting consistency.
6. The inside of your first three functions somehow lost a level of indentation... and there should be a newline before `main()`.

Answer (score -1):

After seeing comments and answer I have tried to improve my code. Please tell me if I can improve further. Can I use any better logic for `display()` function

```
#include <iostream>

#define max 1000

class Queue{
int head,tail;
public:
    int a[max];
    Queue(){
    head=0;
    tail=0;
    }
  void enqueue(int x);
  int dequeue();
  void display();
};

void Queue::enqueue(int x){
a[tail]=x;
if( tail+1==(max-1))
    tail=0;
else
    tail++;
}

int Queue::dequeue(){
int x=a[head];
if(head==(max-1))
    head=0;
else
    head++;
return x;
}

void Queue::display(){
for(int i=head;i<tail;i++){
    std::cout<<a[i]<<" ";
}
}
int main()
{
    Queue queue1;
    queue1.enqueue(15);
    queue1.enqueue(6);
    queue1.enqueue(9);
    queue1.enqueue(8);
    queue1.enqueue(4);
    queue1.display();
    std::cout<<"\n"<<queue1.dequeue()<<"\n";
    queue1.display();
    return 0;
}
```